# Create a Blog Template Page

Tags: php, wp-query, templates

I am trying to create a template that will display a list posts of a specific custom type.  However, I am missing something fundamental.  So far, here is what I have:

#### functions.php

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'query_filter', 1);
function query_filter($query)
{
    if (!$query->is_admin            OR
         $query->is_main_query()     OR
         is_page_template( 'page-events.php' ))
    {
        $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = 3;
    }

    return $query;
}
```

#### page-events.php

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Events Page
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php get_template_part('includes/breadcrumbs'); ?>
<?php get_template_part('includes/top_info'); ?>

<div id="content" class="clearfix fullwidth">
    <div id="left-area">
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <div>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
                    <div>
                        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                            <h2>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                                </a>
                            </h2>
                        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
                    </div>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

As you can see, I still haven't attempted to filter for the custom post type, because currently what is happening is the 'the_content()' is being repeated over and over 100's of times (there should only be about 12 posts).  In addition, the_title() doesn't appear anywhere on the page.

What am I missing?

- William

### UPDATE

After a few suggestions, here is my updated code:

#### EventManager.php

This is where my custom post type is created.

```
add_action('init', 'Initialize');
static function Initialize()
{
register_post_type(Event::POST_TYPE,
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name'                => 'Events',
            'singular_name'       => 'Event',
            'add_new'             => 'Add New',
            'add_new_item'        => 'Add New Event',
            'edit_item'           => 'Edit Event',
            'new_item'            => 'New Event',
            'view_item'           => 'View Event',
            'search_items'        => 'Search Event',
            'not_found'           => 'No Events Found',
            'not_found_in_trash'  => 'No events found in trash',
            'menu_name'           => 'Events',
            ),
        'public'               => true,
        'publicly_queryable'   => true,
        'query_var'            => true,
        'rewrite'              => false,
        'show_ui'              => true,
        'hierarchical'         => false,
        'has_archive'          => true,
        'menu_icon'            => JUPITER_PLUGIN . 'images/small-greyscale.png',
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'author',
            'thumbnail',
            'excerpt',
            'comments',
            'revisions'
            ),
        )
);

global $wp_rewrite;

$gallery_structure = '/' . Event::SLUG . '/%year%/id=%event_id%/%event%';
$wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag("%event%", '([^/]+)', "event=");
$wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag("%event_id%", '([0-9]+)', "event_id=");
$wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('event', $gallery_structure, false);

add_filter('post_type_link', 'gallery_permalink', 10, 3);
function gallery_permalink($permalink, $post_id, $leavename)
{
    $post = get_post($post_id);

    if ($post->post_type == Event::POST_TYPE)
    {
        $rewritecode = array(
            '%year%',
            '%event_id%'
            );

            $unixtime = strtotime($post->post_date);

            $date = explode(" ",date('Y m d H i s', $unixtime));

            $rewritereplace = array(
                $date[0],
                $post->ID
                );

            $permalink = str_replace($rewritecode, $rewritereplace, $permalink);
            return $permalink;
    }
    return $permalink;
}
```

#### archive-event.php

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: Events Archive
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php get_template_part('includes/breadcrumbs'); ?>
<?php get_template_part('includes/top_info'); ?>

<div>
    <div>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div>
            <?php echo the_title(); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

This should be the page that is automatically loaded when I navigate to domain.com/event.  However, that address currently says 'No Results Found'.  If I don't include the custom rewrites when creating the custom post type, then this works as expected. Do I have to include some sort of additional rewrite to redirect the archive to this page?

Comment: The second `if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();` is useless. Remove it and report back.

Comment: I just did - I removed everything between (and including) the redundant inner loop. I had thought that this wasn't right but I found it as an example somewhere else.  Now all I see is the stuff generated by the_content().  When I try to add in an echo the_title() it returns the title of the page but no information about posts.

Comment: Maybe update your code above?

Comment: Check out my updates above -

Comment: Whhere is the `POST_TYPE` constant defined? Also: remove the `Template Name:` header from your `archive-event.php` template file.

Comment: Sorry - it is in a class - it resolves to 'event'

Answer (score 2):

Why reinvent the wheel? [Just create `archive-{posttype}.php`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Post_Types_display), and ensure that `'has_archive'` is set to `true` for the post type.

If your post type is `event`: `archive-event.php`.

Then, WordPress will handle the query automatically. If pretty permalinks are enabled:

```
example.com/{posttype}
```

...will display the archive index page for `{posttype}`.

Comment: I tried this and for some reason it isn't working - it just says 'No Results Found'

Comment: Please post actual code in your question, otherwise it's impossible to troubleshoot or help. In this case: what is your `register_post_type()` call?

Comment: Please check out my updates - I've included my register_post_type and new code.

Answer (score 1):

You've duplicated your loop:

```
   <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
                <div>
                    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

Hence the hundreds or repetitions.

Comment: That said, I agree with Chip.

Comment: I saw the $query->is_admin here (http://wpmu.org/query_posts/) - should it be a method?

Comment: Retracted - that part is correct.